# How do I create a rounded table with controls in the cells?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm exploring the iPhone SDK and want to create and use a UI component like the figure below. A rounded table with cells in which each cell can have some label text, maybe an input text field and an action button that would take it to the next screen. The table should not be screen filling.

But... I can't figure out how to do it or find example code. The 'Table View' always seems to result in a screen filling table and although the 'Table View Cell' looks like what I need I can't find any good examples. I'm sure it's all not that hard, but I just can't find it. Any tips, pointers are appreciated.

(This figure is just an example of the sort of UI component I'm looking for, I'm not build something related to flight tracking...)

[Table like component http://gerodt.homeip.net/table_ui_component.png](http://gerodt.homeip.net/table_ui_component.png)

Gero

Answer (score 4):

Try looking at the "5_CustomTableViewCell" project of the [TableViewSuite](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/TableViewSuite/index.html) code sample from Apple. It should how to create custom subclasses of UITableViewCell.

The short answer is, as alluded to above, you'll want to subclass UITableViewCell and add your custom UI elements to it. For the example you provided, you'd want two different types of cells; one with a label (in light blue) and content (in black) for 4 of your cells, and then a more complex one with additional text on the right.

Answer (score 3):

You want a Grouped style table, which has sections with rounded elements as you lay out instead of filling the screen.

You also want custom table cells, which you can search here to find example code for.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  The other answers show how to add content to the cells, but this answer shows how to make the rounded look you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by other answers, what you want is a grouped TableView with custom UITableViewCells. Take a look at the [Table View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/Introduction/chapter_1_section_1.html), in particular [this section on table view creation](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/chapter_5_section_2.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW11) and [this section on custom cells](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/chapter_6_section_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW18).